# Matlab - highly parallel Tasks in CPU workers or GPU Processors

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

Or how to convert Parfor loops to gpuArray operations ?

Problem at hand : A column-wise operation on large data matrix distributed to multiple CPUs (workers) via parfor.

```
data = 1000 x 200 matrix
[nrows, ncols] = size(data)
parfor ix = 1:ncols
     workerData = data(:,ix);
     colwiseResult(ix) = function(workerData,params);
end
```

Now, how could this be efficiently made to utilize GPUs ? especially since the problem needs to scale up to 1000x1000 matrices (& more )

```
dataGPU = gpuArray(data);
```

But I don't find an easier way of doing column wise operations on GPU. Functions such as arrayfun or bsxfun operate element-by-element which is not what am interested in. Since these are trivially parallel tasks, exploiting multiple processors in the GPUs could be ideal (& avoids bothering with the parfor etc., )

(Well actually, am performing a likelihood calculation that does matrix diagonalization, exponents & products progressively over each data point on the column vector using a for loop inside the Workers). Have checked that all these ops have gpu overloading )

Answer (score 0):

Have you watch this tutorial?

http://www.mathworks.ch/videos/introduction-to-gpu-computing-with-matlab-68770.html

Please check first whether you can use your GPU, since not all GPUs are supported. Afterwards you can pass variables to your GPU or you can include GPUs into your parfor loop like this:

```
parfor ix = 1:10
gd=gpuDevice;
end
```

In the end of day using one GPU is not a big advantage. Please give some more details on your workstation for further information.

Comment: Wow, this is not at all an  answer to the very specific question I have posed with good details. Of course I have looked into the Matlab Intros, help etc., That should be evident even from the information I've provided in the question viz., having read about uses of arrayfun,bsxfun in the gpuArray context. In any case, appreciate your attempt. 2 Teslas c2050 are the workstations. I've a running cluster of ~144 cores where I routinely perform parallel calculations. The question is very specific for my use case and is *NOT* to discuss overall if GPUs are suitable or not.